# Probability conditions

Tags: probability

We have four coins (10 Cent, 10 Cent, 50 Cent, 50 Cent) and choose randomly two of them.
The sum of the two coins is a random variable X.
i) Show that the probability for X to be 20, 60, 100 is 1/6 , 2/3 , 1/6respectively.

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom {4}{2}=\frac{4!}{2!2!}=6 $ ways to pick two coins out of 4 coins. These are relatively easy to list:

There is only one way to choose both of them to be ten cent coints, only one way to choose both of them to be 50 cent coins, and the remaining four ways must contain one 10 cent coin and one 50 cent coin. Thus, probability of choosing 2 10 cent coins is equal to the probability of choosing two 50 cent coins which is equall to $\frac {1}{6}$